# why dot appears when you hover over a link in the list?

Tags: html, css

Good day.

**[Page link for test `http://89.111.180.28/CatalogOfProductsAndServices.php` ]**

Code:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Бытовая техника</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="CatalogOfProductsAndServices.php?id_group=1&amp;id_subgroup=1">Автоаудиоаппаратура</a></li>
...
</ul>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

When i focus on link `<a href="#">Бытовая техника</a>` i see point on first character(see screenshots):

**1) scrrenshot 1**
[image: test1]

**2) screenshot 2**

[image: teest2]

***Tell me please why point show when i focus on link an how delete it?***

Comment: Unfortunately, the link has gone away, so the problem can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `background-image` is added on hover..

```
style.css:1195

#page .items >ul > li > a:hover, #page .items >ul > li.active > a:hover {
    background: url(../../images/li_act.png) left no-repeat;
}
```

Removing that will take care of your dot issue..

Comment: tell me please what programm you use for see it - i see firebug but not see it style...

Comment: @learner I just used the Chrome f12 dev tool.

Comment: nice... I probably missed, thank you.